# Expand tx_news TCA

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I want to add a field in the backend of the new news module. For that I created a new extension with 3 files in it:

ext_emconf.php

```
<?php

$EM_CONF[$_EXTKEY] = array(
    'title' => 'Expand news',
    'description' => 'Expand news',
    'category' => 'fe',
    'author' => 'SOG',
    'author_email' => '-',
    'shy' => '',
    'dependencies' => '',
    'conflicts' => '',
    'priority' => '',
    'module' => '',
    'state' => 'stable',
    'internal' => '',
    'uploadfolder' => 0,
    'createDirs' => '',
    'modify_tables' => '',
    'clearCacheOnLoad' => 0,
    'lockType' => '',
    'author_company' => '',
    'version' => '0.1.0',
    'constraints' => array(
        'depends' => array(
        ),
        'conflicts' => array(
        ),
        'suggests' => array(
        ),
    ),
    '_md5_values_when_last_written' => '',
    'suggests' => array(
    ),
);

?>
```

ext_tables.php

```
<?php
/*if (!defined('TYPO3_MODE')) {
    die ('Access denied.');
}*/
$tempColumns = array(
    'tx_sogexpandnews_test' => array(       
        'exclude' => 0,     
        'label' => 'test',      
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'text',
            'cols' => '30', 
            'rows' => '5',
        )
    ),
);


t3lib_div::loadTCA('tx_news_domain_model_news');
t3lib_extMgm::addTCAcolumns('tx_news_domain_model_news',$tempColumns,1);
t3lib_extMgm::addToAllTCAtypes('tx_news_domain_model_news','tx_sogexpandnews_test', '', 'after:title'));

?>
```

ext_tables.sql

```
#
# Table structure for table 'news'
#
CREATE TABLE tx_news_domain_model_news (
    tx_sogexpandnews_test text
);
```

The field is in the database but I dont see the field in the backend when I wanna create a new news item.

I also checked LocalConfiguation.php and made sure that my extension is under the news extension.

Any idea what I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell why but I deactived news, updated it and installed it again and now I see the field.

Comment: if you make a new db field (or table) you have everytime to run the "compare database" in install tool.

Answer (score 2):

cache - cache - cache ...  always cache.

If you need to be sure, always delete everything in typo3temp and flush all cf_* tables in your db.

(deactivating and reinstalling almost does the same)